# How to export timbre.js buffer to .wav or any other audio file format?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, waveform

So far I figured out how to use `T("rec")` Recorder. But how to export timbre.js buffer to wav or any other audio file format?

```
var rec = T("rec", {timeout:1000}, t).on("ended", function(buffer) {
  // export buffer?
});
```

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs, can you give me some details about the buffer?

Comment: Yes I found this lib, but I think the buffer needs a conversion. There is not so much information available at http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre.js/soundbuffer.html. I am just begining with web audio so so far I don t know how to use recorderJs with timbreJs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you check if this works,
I have just modified the [source](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs), changed it into single channel and removed worker bit.

```
    var rec = T("rec", {timeout:1000}, t).on("ended", function(buffer) {
      // export buffer?

      // I am assuming that buffer is of format {buffer: bufferArray, samplerate: samplerate}


      var buf = buffer.buffer[0],      // buf = a Float32Array of data
          sr = buffer.samplerate    //sample rate of the data
      ;

      var dataview = encodeWAV(buf, sr);
      var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], { type: 'audio/wav' });

      // do something with audioBlob, may be provide it as link to be downloaded
    });


    function encodeWAV(buf, sr){
      var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + buf.length * 2);
      var view = new DataView(buffer);

      /* RIFF identifier */
      writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
      /* chunk size (= file length - 8) */
      view.setUint32(4, 36 + buf.length * 2, true);
      /* RIFF type */
      writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
      /* format chunk identifier */
      writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
      /* format chunk length */
      view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
      /* sample format (raw) */
      view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
      /* channel count */
      view.setUint16(22, 1, true);
      /* sample rate */
      view.setUint32(24, sr, true);
      /* byte rate (sample rate * block align) */
      view.setUint32(28, sr *2 , true);
      /* block align (channel count * bytes per sample) */
      view.setUint16(32, 2, true);
      /* bits per sample */
      view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
      /* data chunk identifier */
      writeString(view, 36, 'data');
      /* data chunk length */
      view.setUint32(40, buf.length * 2, true);

      floatTo16BitPCM(view, 44, buf);

      return view;
    }    

    function floatTo16BitPCM(output, offset, input){
      for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++, offset+=2){
        var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, input[i]));
        output.setInt16(offset, s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7FFF, true);
      }
    }

    function writeString(view, offset, string){
      for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
        view.setUint8(offset + i, string.charCodeAt(i));
      }
    }
```

fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/87oujvt7/2/)

Comment: Looks good but the code produces an empty wav. However the wave file is valid which is a good sign. I have created a js fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/cru4xjsb/1/ with your code based on a timbre api demo.

Comment: I have changed, ```buf = buffer.buffer``` into ```buf = buffer.buffer[0]```, now it should work

Comment: Impressive knowledge!